# More subtotal options in pivot tables - at end, only for rows not for columns?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, dax

I have pivot tables that are based on a power pivot model.

I haven't found many subtotal options.

**Problem A**:
If I have quarter and month as column labels, then the subtotals become arranged as below

```
April 2015, May 2015, June 2015, Q2 2015, Jul 2015, Aug 2015, Sep 2015, Q3 2015
```

**Is it possible to put all subtotals on the end?**

So that the result becomes as below.

```
April 2015, May 2015, June 2015, Jul 2015, Aug 2015, Sep 2015, Q2 2015, Q3 2015
```

**Problem B:**

If I choose to show subtotals, the subtotals show on both columns and rows. I see an option to disable grand totals on column or rows, but I don't see the same option for subtotals. **Is it possible to show subtotals for only columns or rows?**

So that the following

```
April 2015, May 2015, June 2015, Q2 2015, Jul 2015, Aug 2015, Sep 2015, Q3 2015
Product A1
Product A2
Product A subtotal
Product B1
Product B2
Product B subtotal
```

can become

```
April 2015, May 2015, June 2015, Jul 2015, Aug 2015, Sep 2015
Product A1
Product A2
Product A subtotal
Product B1
Product B2
Product B subtotal
```

or

```
April 2015, May 2015, June 2015, Q2 2015, Jul 2015, Aug 2015, Sep 2015, Q3 2015
Product A1
Product A2
Product B1
Product B2
```

If it matters, my pivot tables are based on a power pivot model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot group subtotals at the end in pivot tables, but there is a workaround if you'd like to explore it. You can convert a pivot table to cube formulas, which act as regular Excel formulas, but reference an external data source directly. Examples are [here](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/category/cube-formulas/?order=asc). ([Extra reading](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/searchresults/?q=cube+formulas)) Once your pivot is converted to cube formulas you can arrange everything exactly as you'd like. This can be fussy, but if your analysis is of the write once, read many variety, then it can be worth it.

You can turn subtotals on or off by source table field, so that you can selectively control which row- and column-filter labels get subtotals. See image sample below. Just right click on the label from a particular source field and select the subtotal option:

[image: Subtotal by group]